# How to hide the categories menu on an extra check-out step I added?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, menu, topmenu

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I have added an extra step in the check-out where I plan to present up-sell products but the menu on the top with all the categories is taking way too much real estate - I would like the customers to only see the up-sell products here....

### **How can I hide the categories menu and the entire header on that particular step of the check-out?**

Here are the screenshots:

1. How it is on my website now (the up-sell/cross-sell products are showing up at the very bottom next to the test item):

[image]

2. Here is a picture from another website - this is how I would like it to look (no menu or header at the top):

[image]

Comment: can you send any screenshot?

Comment: @stalinrajindian Thank you for your willingness to help. I posted the screenshots in the original post above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a layout update for your cart page (either via your custom module, or in your themes `local.xml` - i.e. `app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` - by removing the particular area inside a `<checkout_cart_index>` node (and/or inside a `<checkout_onepage_index>` node if you'd like to hide parts from the checkout as well).

For removing the complete header add this inside the layout XML file as described above:

```
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <remove name="header"/>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

This should lead to something like that:
[image]

*) Please note that your customer will have a hard time on finding back to where they came from if you remove the whole header!

---

If you'd just like to remove the categories (i.e. the top navigation) you can refer to the same like so:

```
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="topMenu">
            <remove name="catalog.topnav" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

This should lead to something like this:
[image]

---

The same concept applies on the `<checkout_onepage_index>` node. Just add the same structure for this node as well.

This should be working as long as your current theme is respecting given layout rules specified by Magento.

You can check for example your themes (i.e. `app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme}/layout/.page.xml`) and the base' (i.e. `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/.page.xml`) default page layout definition to see what block are called (where/how).

Some good read on this topic can be found for example here:

- https://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates/